# GCC Linux DB2 COBOL compiler option issues

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, db2, cobol

Compiling/Linking COBOL code on a RHEL 8.6, which compiles fine but then when it tries to link I get an error with one of the variables:
cob2 -F//etc/cob2.cfg -v <cobolprog.cbl> -L/lib64 -ldb2 -I/include/cobol_a/ -q"size(16384K) -o cobolprog

The output is /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible lib64/libdb2.so when searching for -ldb2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2
If I remove the -ldb2 I get 'undefined reference to 'SQLGSTRT', 'SQLGALOC etc

When I try this with lib32 and -ldb2 I dont see issues?

I did try using the -q64 on the cmd line but apparently this is not supported on linux.

db2level
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.0.0", "s1906101300", "DYN1906101300AMD64", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/IBM/db2/V11.5"

cob2 -V
Program  cob2
Version  1.1.0
Built    Mon Sep 27 10:39:30 2021

Tried 32 bit which compiles the cobol fine, but it now seems to have an issue with linking a static library I need:
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib/Scrtl.0(.text+0x1c): unresolvable R_386_GOTOFF relocation against symbol '__libc_csu_fini'

Comment: Please edit your question to add essential FACTS, specifically what version of the db2 client do you have? (i.e. paste the plain text output of its `db2level` command into your question). also your version of gcc.

Comment: The version of the db2 client is V11.5

Comment: Do not use comments to add facts because comments are not searchable. Need two facts from you. (1) Please edit your question with the __full__ plain text output of the `db2level` command (it is located in the bin directory of the db2 client on the same hostname where you see the message). It is __not__ enough to write the version name alone.   (2) please show the plain text output of the command `cobc -V`.  Understand that the bitness of the cobol toolchain must match the bitness and architecture of the .so library.

Comment: Looks like the output of `db2level` is missing the required information (bitness and architecture). You get the message from ld because the bitness/architecture of the provided library does not match that requested , hence it skips the library.   Separately I see you are using "fixpack 0" of the V11.5 , which is __always__ a mistake, so you should promptly upgrade to the current fixpack (at February 2023 that is v11.5.8.0 available via https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6830623

Comment: The gcc label is wrong, you may want to drop that. As noted in the real answer: IBM COBOL on x86 is a 32 bit only product, of you want 64 bit switch to GnuCOBOL, compiling with ’cobc -std=ibm’.

Comment: Currently trying the 32 bit which compiles the cobol fine, but it now seems to have an issue with linking a static library I need:

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib/Scrtl.0(.text+0x1c): unresolvable R_386_GOTOFF relocation against symbol '__libc_csu_fini'

Comment: Do not abuse stackoverflow questions by adding a new different symptom to a previously answered question that has an entirely different symptom. Instead create a new question and put all relevant details into that new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using IBM COBOL for Linux on x86 version 1.1.

According to IBM's documentation at  this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-linux-x86/1.1?topic=options-addr)
the ADDR compiler option specifies whether to create a 32-bit or 64-bit object file.

Additionally, as you are on version 1.1 (the currently available version as of February-2023), the documentation also has this specific relevant note:

> Note: The ADDR(64) and -q64 options are not currently supported. The
> compiler accepts and ignores these options and defaults to ADDR(32).

This means that your object file is 32-bit, but you are trying to link (`ld`) with the 64-bit Db2 libraries, and consequently `ld` skips the incomptabile library with the message that you see. You should Link with the 32-bit Db2 libraries instead, they are in the `lib32` directory of the Db2 client, so arrange for this in your command line options.